# multiple functions executed but not running correctly

Tags: c++, sorting

I was trying to do the sorting algorithm using c++ where i execute the insertion, bubble & selection sort in 1 main method. My objective is to print out the number of copied inside the swap. However, I couldn't understand why the results seems to be different when I execute 1 function at a time and execute 3 together.

Result of executing 3 functions at the same time:

> Bubble sort : Number of copied -> 78
>
> Selection sort : Number of copied -> 15
>
> Insertion sort : Number of copied -> 0

Result of executing 1 functions at the same time:

> Bubble sort : Number of copied -> 78
>
> Selection sort : Number of copied -> 21
>
> Insertion sort : Number of copied -> 57

Thanks.

```
int main()
{       
    cout<<"\n"<<"Sorting Functions"<<"\n\n";

    bubblesort(values, size);
    selectionsort(values, size);
    insertionsort(values, size);

}

void bubblesort(int arr[], int size)
{
//sorts descending
    int countbubble=0; // Initialize number of comparisons at 0
    int copiedbubble = 0; // Initialize number of copied at 0
    bool flag;
    for (int m=size-1; m>0; m--)
    {
        flag=false;
        for (int j=0; j<m; j++)
        { 
            countbubble++; // Increase 1 whenever it loop in.
            if (arr[j] < arr[j+1])
            {
            //swap value at index j with value at index j+1
            swap(arr,j,j+1);
            copiedbubble +=3; // Increase 3     
            flag = true; 
            }
        }   

        if (!flag)  //already sorted; nothing to swap
        break;
    }
    // Display the number of comparison and the number of copied
    cout<<"Bubble sort : Number of comparisons -> "<<countbubble<<" | Number of copied -> "<<copiedbubble<<"\n";        
    //display(arr,size);
}

void selectionsort(int arr[], int size)
{
    //sorts ascending
    int countselection=0; // Initialize number of comparisons at 0
    int copiedselection = 0; // Initialize number of copied at 0
    int max;
    for (int m=size-1; m>0; m--)
    {
        max=0;
        for (int j=1; j<=m; j++)
        {
            countselection++;
            if (arr[j] > arr[max])
            {
                max = j;
            }

        }
        if (m!=max) 
        {    
            int tmp = arr[m];
            arr[m] = arr[max];
            arr[max] = tmp;
            copiedselection +=3; // Increase 3
        }

        //display(arr,size);
    }
    // Display the number of comparison and the number of copied
    cout<<"Selection sort : Number of comparisons -> "<<countselection<<" | Number of copied -> "<<copiedselection<<"\n";
}

void insertionsort(int arr[], int size){
//sorts ascending
        int i, tmp, k;
    int count=0; // Initialize number of comparisons at 0
    int copied = 0; // Initialize number of copied at 0
     for( i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
        tmp = arr[ i ];
        k = i - 1;
        count++;
        while( k >= 0 && tmp < arr[k] ) { 
            arr[ k+1 ] = arr[ k ];
            k--;
            copied +=3;
         }
        arr[ k+1 ] = tmp;


      }//display(arr,size);
// Display the number of comparison and the number of copied
    cout<<"Insertion sort : Number of comparisons -> "<<count<<" | Number of copied -> "<<copied<<"\n";
}
```

Comment: There's possibly an error in your code. Maybe we can see something?

Comment: Hi Roger, I have just added in the code. thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "executing at the same time"?

Comment: eg. only run selectionsort(values, size); in the main method vs when I run all 3 together. result won't not be the same.

Answer (score 2):

This occurs because insertion sort does not perform any copying on an already sorted list. So if you sorted the list first with selection sort, you see 0 copies because of this effect. Doing it individually will actually do the sorting like you want.

Recall the complexity of insertion sort is O(n) on a sorted list (best case).

Comment: Hi Pippin, thanks for the reply.

I understand your explanation. However, how could that happened when the value[] is calling from the same set of unsorted array?